# Unable to connect remote server on ipv6 using federated engine mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, federated-storage-engine

How can we connect to the remote mysql server which has ipv6 address using one of the federated engine mysql table on different ipv6 server. if yes i wanted to know the format.

CREATE TABLE usageinfo 
(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  controllerId VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  slotId VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  startdate DATE NULL,
  starttime TIME NULL,
  enddate DATE NULL,
  endtime TIME NULL
)ENGINE=FEDERATED
  CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@**2222:2222:f:2222::10:3306**/dbthirdeye/usageinfo';

remote server : 2222:2222:f:2222::10:3306

my table created successfully

now when i insert from local server it throws below error

Unable to connect to foreign data source: Can't connect to MySQL server on '2607' (101 "Network is unreac

i guess its the issue with ipv6 address format while creating table

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-connection.html for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be resolved by adding the entry in hosts file.

for example

2222:d212:f:345a::11 testserver

Now you can refer "testserver" in